# Swift 4 Table View Getting Wrong Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having problems selecting the right cells within my table view. My code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MyTableView: UITableView
var cellsArray = [ "0" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellsArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@IBAction func MyButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 4 ,section: 0)
    let cell = MyTableView.cellForRow(at: myIndexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

[This is the application when it's running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPcIX.png)

The problem is when I press the button without scrolling the tableview nothing happens, but if I scroll down so the current view includes cells labeled 4/5/6 and press the button both cells labeled "4" and "0" have their background colors set to yellow.

I would ultimately like to know why this is the case since it's been effecting more than just background, like when doing a for loop to sum the cell heights to auto change the height of the tableview, the cells not in view crash the program as it's returning null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on why is this!

**After button press when 4 is in view**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are being reused - you can only get reference to the visible cells.

```
let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 4 ,section: 0)
let cell = MyTableView.cellForRow(at: myIndexPath)
cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
```

`cell` in your case is nil when row number 4 isn't visible. If you wanna change behaviour in the cells you should modify the model and call for example `reloadData` on your UITableView.

Comment: It's just then not entirely clear why it would then change the "0" row to have a yellow background if its not visible or row 4